# Flutter. Foreground blur effect background Views

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

During handling blur action with Flutter you might have issue with forcing blur effect on background. By using `Stack` and inner `BackdropFilter`. Blur on the foreground view, effect other view outside bounds. How to avoid that?

```
//.....
      child: new Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Image.asset(
            'assets/bg_img.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
          ),
          new Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: new Center(
              child: new Center(
                child: new ClipRect(
                  child: new BackdropFilter(
                    filter: new ui.ImageFilter.blur(
                      sigmaX: 6.0,
                      sigmaY: 6.0,
                    ),
//.....
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to configure blur effect with `Stack` Views you need to setup `AlignmentDirectional` on the `Stack`. Ex. below.

```
child: Stack(alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center, 
        children: <Widget>[Column(
             //.. Your blur effect here.
```